# Why is android studio decompiling classes from my projects when I open them?

Tags: android-studio, decompiler

Android Studio was automatically updated on my system to to 4.0.1, from version 3.2, however since I found that 4.0.1 had potential bugs, I installed a previous version (3.5.3) and I when opening one of my projects which is only a small simple test project and seemed to take an age loading, the last dialog, I see before it opens is

Title:  "Loading Project..."

Body:   "Decompiling class CountDownTimer.class

when in previous versions I haven't seen this behaviour and I cant find any "decompiler" options in Settings either and the question is Why is Android Studio decompiling my class files, by default?  why would it need to? what is the rationale?

Comment: If it can't find the sources, that's generally what you'd want and expect.

Comment: Why wouldnt it find the source code? when its always present within the project?  In software engineering terms, I expect the IDE to compile java source code into bytecode, I dont expect it to decompile anything as that falls within the realms of reverse engineering.  This behaviour is certainly not what I'd want or expect, hence the reason for the question.

Comment: "Always present within the project" -- well, that depends on whether your project is set up right -- whether the source directory is actually registered as a source directory, f/e, so its contents are indexed and recognized. And a touch of light reverse engineering is darned handy when you hit a bug inside a library you don't have source to, which is perhaps the main reason I appreciate this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  There is no doubt my project is set up correctly.  I get what your are saying  I have found many bugs in API's by compiling my own code.  So if Android Studio hits a bug in the API code or some class or jar dependency,  it decompiles it, in order that it can present the source code to the developer?  It still doesnt make sense that it instead of automatically compiling my source code into class files it is doing the exact opposite and automatically decompiling my compiled classes into source code everytime I open my projects.